# Move Web Directory to Raid Array

Tags: centos, raid

I want to improve the performance of a web application running on Apache, so I created a Raid Array on /dev/md0.

Now I need to figure out how to move the application to the array and make sure that Apache will still serve it when someone accesses my domain.

> Web application is in the directory: /var/www/html - Raid Array device
>   is: /dev/md0

How do I make the application run on the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
# cd /var/www
# mv html old-html
# mkdir -m400 html
# mount /dev/md0 html
# chmod 775 html
# cp -pr old-html/* html
```

That should mirror the current contents of `/var/www/html` onto the RAID array.

Some notes:

1. The mount command might need tweaking, and ultimately you will want to have an entry in `/etc/fstab` for it. I assume whatever guide you're using to set up the RAID array has got the correct mount and fstab info.
2. The permissions on `/var/www/html` are simply what I have here. You might need to adjust them to match your site's existing perms.

   (The permissions are set "twice" because the mount point and the volume root are not the same thing. If you set the mount point to 775 or whatever, too, you have a potential to mask a mount failure by having a readable and writable mount point. You want the system to yell loudly when this happens. Thus 0400.)
3. The `cp` command won't copy dotfiles at the top level of your site. If for some strange reason you have a top-level `.htaccess` file, for example, instead of having the root site config in `/etc/httpd` somewhere, you'll have to copy that file over by hand. (I could have given you a more complex command that would copy top-level dotfiles, too, but there seems little point.)

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -aHS /var/www/old-html/ /var/www/html/
```

Will copy all files 1:1 and all permissions.